# Makefile for bi-directional codec

Tags: makefile

Once upon a time I wrote a little codec to convert from IPython Notebooks (`.ipynb`) to "decorated" Python code and vice-versa.  This has proved quite useful to work with the source code corresponding to a notebook.  In my team we use that to store the decorated Python source in our git repos (rather than the sometimes huge `.ipynb` files). We can diff notebooks (with other notebooks or along the version graph), refactor them in our favorite IDE, etc.  We typically have a few example notebooks in our codebase as examples and part of the documentation (they are hydrated and run when we build the docs).

The syntax is:

```
nb2py example.ipynb -o example.py
```

and

```
py2nb example.py -o example.ipynb
```

Now, I'd like to set up a `Makefile` to update all `.py` and `.ipynb` files, in such a way that *whichever form of a file was changed last prevails*.

For example, when I modify `foo.py`, then `foo.ipynb` would be updated to reflect that change.  But if instead I edited `foo.ipynb` (presumably via Jupyter), then `foo.py` would be updated to reflect that change.

I have this simple `Makefile`, and it almost does what I want:

```
.PHONY: clean update nb py

# py --> nb
PY_SRC = $(wildcard *.py)
NB_DST = $(PY_SRC:.py=.ipynb)

# nb --> py
NB_SRC = $(wildcard *.ipynb)
PY_DST = $(NB_SRC:.ipynb=.py)

%.ipynb: %.py
    py2nb $< -o $@ && touch -r $< $@

%.py: %.ipynb
    nb2py $< -o $@ && touch -r $< $@

clean:
    tbd

update: nb py

nb: $(NB_DST)

py: $(PY_DST)
```

The `touch -r` command sets the target file to have exactly the same timestamp than the source, so that it wouldn't be updated again in a second `make`, and it would also not update back the source.

I can do: `make nb` and it updates all stale `.ipynb` files that are older than a corresponding `.py`. And I can `make py` to go the other way. There is much huffing and puffing from `make`, however, warning me about the obvious circularity of the whole setup. But it does the right thing.

The `update` target doesn't fully work. The `py --> nb` direction works, but not the other way.

And finally, I do not know how to implement `clean`. Say, for example, that in my context I would like `clean` to delete any `.ipynb` that would **not** update a corresponding `.py` (either because the `.py` doesn't exist or because it is older).

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile`. You could be interested by [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) or by [`omake`](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/omake.html)

Comment: As other people already noted, make is an improper tool for this task. And although some tricks, such as using recursive make, to effectively split the DAG, could work, but it makes much more sense simply to use another tool. I'd think of implementing this functionality in pure Python, as it's already used anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider splitting this into separate Makefiles to conceal the essential circularity from `make`:

---

**Makefile**

```
update:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile_py2nb
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile_nb2py

clean:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile_py2nb clean
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile_nb2py clean

.PHONY: clean update
```

---

**Makefile_nb2py**

```
NB_SRC = $(wildcard *.ipynb)
PY_DST = $(NB_SRC:.ipynb=.py)

py: $(PY_DST)

clean:
    :

%.py: %.ipynb
    nb2py $< -o $@ && touch -r $< $@

.PHONY: py clean
```

---

**Makefile_py2nb**

```
PY_SRC = $(wildcard *.py)
NB_DST = $(PY_SRC:.py=.ipynb)

nb: $(NB_DST)

clean:
    for nb in $(NB_DST); do test -e $${nb} && test ! $${nb} -nt $${nb%%.*}.py && rm $${nb}; done

%.ipynb: %.py
    py2nb $< -o $@ && touch -r $< $@

.PHONY: nb clean
```

---

That also implements `clean` in the way you described.  Note that for the clean mode you described, that naturally goes (only) in the makefile for building `.ipynb` files from `.py` files, because that's the one where the former are the built targets, where it makes sense for them to be subject to cleaning.  The construction of the file precludes any .ipynb files being handled there that do not have a corresponding .py file, as it should.

You run `make` normally, and it selects the standard `Makefile`.  That performs a submake with each of the other makefiles, each of which only sees one-way dependencies.

Comment: this is lovely, thank you. One very small edit for clean: my `make` ends in error 2 if the directory is already clean (presumably the `for` loop executes nothing and perhaps `errno` is ill-defined). Anyway, this is fixed with adding `touch /dev/null` at the end, like this: `for nb in $(NB_DST); do [[ -e $${nb} ]] && [[ ! $${nb} -nt $${nb%%.*}.py ]] && rm $${nb}; done; touch /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Make isn't designed for this sort of thing.   It doesn't like circular dependencies.   Trying to get around it using pure make would likely create a hard-to-maintain makefile.   I would try creating an artifact file, and using shell logic to do the copy as follows:

```
.%.updated: %.py %.ipynb
    @if [ $*.py -nt $*.ipynb ]; then \
       py2nb $*.py -o $*.ipynb; \
    else \
       nb2py $*.ipynb-o $*.py;
    touch $@
```

When the rule finishes running, it will create `.foo.updated`, which will be newer than the `.py` or `.ipynb` files, so long as noone modifies either of the two.   As soon as someone makes a modification, it will copy in the correct direction.

This assumes that both the `.py` and `.ipynb` files both exist.   If this might not be the case, you can add some order only dependencies to create them as so:

```
%.py : | %.ipynb
    touch -d "1 second ago" $@; touch $^

%.ipynb: | %.py
    touch -d "1 second ago" $@; touch $^
```

These will make the dependency newer than the target, and then fall through the `.%.updated` rule, which will run the copy in the correct direction.